# My webshop is broken

Tags: magento2

My webshop agoshop.at is broken.
A designer have changed some text but nothing else in backend.
Maybe someone can help me how I can solve it.
Kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade; bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f; bin/magento cache:flush;
```